# Difference between CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-boot.iso and CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso

Tags: linux, centos, installation, iso, anaconda

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/8/isos/x86_64/

What's the difference between CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-boot.iso and CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso?

I imagine the DVD is an installer which let's you choose which packages to install during initial installation. I might offer live boot, not sure.

The one that with -boot I imagine is a Live CD (or USB) to try the OS or maintenance/rescue of an existing system. Does this one also provide an installer for a minimal system so I don't have to use 7GB bandwidth and disk space? Where can I get such an ISO, I don't see a minimal intaller, just "-boot"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *-boot* images are designed for installation over the network, external disk or a file server, typically used to install large numbers of computers. Additionally, the package collections  allow the select a minimal setup. More info can be found [here](https://people.centos.org/jperrin/Kickstart2.html)

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded it and tried booting it. It was asking for repo. I figured it was a net install. I don't want to download a 7GB ISO file at this time, I have used a 636 MB ISO to install CentOS7 and used yum for everything else I needed.